# Why do LINQ methods have an optional type

Tags: c#, linq

Many LINQ methods take the form of

```
MethodName<Type>();
```

It appears that when calling these methods the `Type` is optional.  For example, these two statements seem to produce identical results:

```
var a = someStringList.First<string>();
var b = someStringList.First();
```

Why would I want to type out the `<string>` portion of that statement?  Are there cases where it has utility?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First of all, note that this applies to any generic method, not just LINQ methods.

In general, you do not need to specify the type on generic method, because, usually, the type can be inferred from usage.  For example:

```
 T SomeFunc<T>(T arg) {....}

 var x = SomeFunc("Hello World");
```

Since we used a string for the parameter, the compiler decide that `T` is a string, and therefore we concludes that the method will return a string.

Other times, it cannot deduce it:

```
 T SomeOtherFunc<T>(string arg) {....}

 var x = SomeOtherFunc("Hello World");      // error : cannot infer type
```

IN these case, you have to specify the type:

```
 var x = SomeOtherFunc<int>("Hello World");      // x will be an int.
```

If you really want to, say for added clarity, you could specify the type even when it can be deduced, but it must be correct:

```
 T SomeFunc<T>(T arg) {....}

 var x = SomeFunc<string>("Hello World");    // OK 
 var y = SomeFunc<int>("Hello World");       // Error
```

FInally, remember, that for extension methods, like `First<>` in your example, the object is actually the first parameter, so that can be used in type inference.  `First<>` would be defined as:

```
 public static T First<T>(this IEnumerable<T> coll) ;
```

Comment: Ahh, this makes perfect sense.  Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

Because in the second one type is inferred by the compiler automatically based on the type of `someStringList`.Since it is an `IEnumerable<string>` compiler resolves the generic argument type as `string`.

> Ok, so it sounds like it could be used to cast if needed...why not use .Cast?

Because `Cast` method takes a non-generic `IEnumerable` as it's first parameter so there is no way to infer the type and that's why you need to provide it.

Comment: Ok, so it sounds like it could be used to cast if needed...why not use `.Cast<T>`?

Comment: If you explicitly specify the type, it has to match the actual type of the argument being passed in. There's no casting going on.